# jquery is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

please try this link for getting  my code. its working in all browsers not in IE. thank you

[carousel](http://122.165.56.88/jquery.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the look of your carousel.js file the problem is probably not jQuery but your javascript.

A few tips:

- The global object is window not document.
- you are using document.all.  When using jQuery **use it** for selecting elements from the DOM! That's the whole point.
- you're not using var in your functions but are using it for globals.  You've got it backwards.  Skipping var in functions creates a bunch of global variables, which will get clobbered eventually.  Use var to keep your variables local to your function.

Comment: the only time document.all should ever be used is to implement hacks to overcome IE's getElementById/getElementsByName bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Ive just checked the [compatibility](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility)  and it said:

> There are known problems with: Internet Explorer 1.0-5.x
>
> jQuery generally works with Konqueror and Firefox 1.0.x, but there may be some unexpected bugs since we do not test them as regularly as Firefox 2.0+, IE6+, Opera 9+ and Safari 3+.

Comment: running IE6 is bad enough.. but who out there is running IE1.0 and IE1.5? - I have no problem whatsoever with jQuery failing in these browsers!

Answer (score 0):

i've run this on my side on IE 8

IE cannot pick up your document.id.src in your carousel.js.

replace where you are assigning srcs to id tags with using the document.getElementById("id name")

example:
document.getElementById("but_img1").src

when testing always check the errors at the bottom of the page (where it shows loading status - Done - with an exclamation mark).

hope this helps.